# Library for Automatically posting alerts to multiple social profiles

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, twitter, social-networking

I am running a discussion website and I want that whenever a new topic is added to my website, a tweet to twitter, status to Facebook page, and news to other social profiles of my website should be posted automatically. So is there any all-in-one library available for that? I know about Twitter and Facebook APIs but since we have many profiles on various social networks, so if there any easy solution available that can do the task in one click of the user on my website?